# Reference for time-derivatives of measure-valued "processes"

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives, reference-request, optimal-transport

The notion of the weak derivative of a process of probability measures $(\mu_t)_{t\geq 0}$ in optimal transport theory seems to be so basic that, e.g., in "Optimal Transport, old and new" the author hardly bothers to even define it. Apparently it's somehow defined by "duality" with smooth functions, maybe somewhat like $\partial_t \int \phi \,d\mu = \int \phi'\,d(\partial_t \mu)$ for test functions $\phi$.

For some more context, it appears for example in the conservation of mass formula (which I cannot explain any further, unfortunately):

$$\partial_t \mu + \nabla \cdot (\mu \xi) = 0.$$

Where can I read about the definition of $\partial_t \mu$, what conditions are necessary and perhaps some explicit examples?

*(As an aside I also wonder what $\mu \xi$ could mean for some "velocity field" (vector field?) $\xi$).*

Comment: You're right, it is defined by duality and the concept behind is that of 'weak derivatives' which is a crucial cornerstone of modern PDE theory. Thus, you will find this topic discussed in every reasonably big and modern PDE book, classic choice would be the one of Evans, e.g.

Comment: @Tobsn Thanks. I have seen weak and distributional derivatives at one point. Is the connection here that one can lift Radon measures to distributions?

Comment: I would have a look at Santambrogio's book; I think e.g. the weak formulation of the continuity equation is explained more precisely there than in Villani.